# How to stop SaaS users from joining and making duplicate companies rather then joining an existing setup company with other co-workers?

Tags: logic

We have a SaaS application that allows users to join from our Website. When they join they select a company to be part of... How can we stop them from creating a duplicate company if the company already exists that other co-workers are joined in already. For example, Jim joins and does company "NewCo". Then Steph joins and does "NewCo USA".

We are thinking of using the ending of the email address which shows the company name and programmatically assigning them.

We are looking for creative ideas around how we could do this another way.

We do not want to allow them to search and expose who all of our company's are...

Comment: I would send them a custom link after they validate their email address, that is for their specific company. You can implement your idea about using the email address to determine the company.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.